# Uinput doesn't work with Xorg

Tags: xorg, 18.04, evdev

I try to use uinput to make simple autoclicker. It worked just fine in linux mint 18.3, but something is wrong on Ubuntu 18.04.

This is what `xinput list` show:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                    id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Optical Mouse                    id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SIGMACHIP USB Keyboard                        id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ uinput_autoclicker                            id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard                   id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                                  id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                                  id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                                  id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 Camera: USB2.0 Camera                  id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ SIGMACHIP USB Keyboard                        id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ SIGMACHIP USB Keyboard                        id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

And `evtest` output:

```
Event: time 1528384945.343765, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 272 (BTN_LEFT), value 1
Event: time 1528384945.343765, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 272 (BTN_LEFT), value 0
Event: time 1528384945.343765, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1528384945.368880, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 272 (BTN_LEFT), value 1
Event: time 1528384945.368880, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 272 (BTN_LEFT), value 0
Event: time 1528384945.368880, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1528384945.394015, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 272 (BTN_LEFT), value 1
Event: time 1528384945.394015, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 272 (BTN_LEFT), value 0
Event: time 1528384945.394015, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1528384945.419128, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 272 (BTN_LEFT), value 1
Event: time 1528384945.419128, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 272 (BTN_LEFT), value 0
Event: time 1528384945.419128, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1528384945.444304, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 272 (BTN_LEFT), value 1
Event: time 1528384945.444304, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 272 (BTN_LEFT), value 0
Event: time 1528384945.444304, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
```

and so on…

`grep -e "Using input driver " /var/log/Xorg.0.log`:

```
[  3012.644] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'uinput_autoclicker'
```

Same problem if I try emulating keyboard/etc. How can I fix it?

**UPD:** I use cinnamon installed on XUbuntu. `xorg.conf` is auto-generated by `nvidia-settings`.

Comment: Try on Gnome on Linux Mint. If it doesn't work either, then it's due to the fact that Gnome doesn't actually have plain Xorg but something else and Xorg compatibility support.